# Software quality assurance/IPv6 : validate IPv6 stack

Tags: tools, quality-assurance, open-source, linux

I need to check an IPv6 implementation on my router's software using a free tool/program. I'm looking for any available tool to help IPv6 certification: I need to validate and verify whether or not the IPv6 stack is compliant with related IPv6 RFC(s) and/or amendment(s).

- Validation DHCPv6 client
- Validate ravd daemon
- Validate DHCPv6 server
- etc

If there are no free tools/programs, how can I validate the IPv6 stack for certification?

Comment: is it your own, in house, implementation or are you interested in somekind of acceptance test for an  implementation you bought ?

Comment: I've reworded your question to make the question clearer - if this is not what you were asking, please edit to clarify.

Comment: Thanks Paulk Kate, In fact I got a router with IPv6 full support and I want to check if it's well working. So If there is no specific tool to run, an acceptance tests if available are also very helpful for me.
For example, check DHCPv6 client, my DHCPv6 server, radvd daemon when connect to IPv6 platform, etc

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware there is no "one hit" tool to check every part of your configuration.

However, there are [online checkers](https://ip6.nl/) which will check your IPv6 setup from an external perspective.